# Displaying SVG file on android - zero sized drawable?

Tags: android, svg

I am using the svg-android library to load and display SVG images:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgLoginLogo);

// Set the background color to white
iv.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

// Parse the SVG file from the resource
SVG svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(), R.raw.android);

// Get a drawable from the parsed SVG and set it as the drawable for the ImageView
Drawable d = svg.createPictureDrawable();
iv.setImageDrawable(d);
```

Problem is the drawable I get has zero dimensions, so it is not visible.

What is wrong here ?

Thanks

Shimon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this to create a drawable:

```
public static Bitmap createBitmap(InputStream in, int w, int h) {
    com.larvalabs.svgandroid.SVG svg = new SVGBuilder().readFromInputStream(in).build();

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    Picture pic = svg.getPicture();
    canvas.drawPicture(pic, new Rect(0, 0, w, h));
    return bitmap;
}
```

Notice that you must care about recycling the bitmap after done with it.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Turns out the problem was a missing line: had to add the line: imageView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);